# How to use javascript string /n character

Tags: javascript, html, string, escaping

I am working on a div that will allow the user to click on a list of words

- *about us
- faq
- services
- contact

In a div located right next to those words, the content will change using javascript string replacement. The issue that I am running into is using literal escape characters to put the strings for these paragraphs on new lines.

Here is an example of the javascript code I am using.

```
else if(x == "faqButton"){
    //alert("FAQ Button");
    document.getElementById('informationContent').innerHTML ="FAQ Click";   
}
```

The content 'faq click' will eventually be replaced once i figure out how to format the text correctly.
Obviously this isnt the whole code, but i only need one example to fix the rest. How would I put 'click' on the next line, so in the new div, it would be placed like

FAQ 
Click

Ive tried

```
document.getElementById('informationContent').innerHTML ="FAQ /n Click";
document.getElementById('informationContent').innerHTML ="FAQ" + /n + "Click";
```

Neither one worked and the bottom one broke my code completely.

Help please

Comment: Have you tried \n? Also, <br /> is the way to make line breaks in HTML

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you set `innerHTML`, you're supplying **HTML**. Line breaks in source text are just whitespace in HTML (think of the line breaks in HTML files that you write). (That is, unless it's in a `pre` element or any element with `white-space: pre` or similar applied to it via CSS.)

To actually have things appear on different lines, you typically either use `<br>` between them, or use a series of block-level elements. The latter is probably more common for navigation.

So for instance:

```
this.innerHTML = "FAQ<br>Index";
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/elazug/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/elazug/1/edit)

Or

```
this.innerHTML = "<div>FAQ</div><div>Index</div>";
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/elazug/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/elazug/2/edit)

Again, using elements (typically `li` elements with `display: block` applied to them via CSS, inside a `ul` element, although the new [`nav` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-nav-element) is gaining popularity) is more common in navigation.

Comment: Ive tried that 
document.getElementById('informationContent').innerHTML ="FAQ" + <br /> + "Click";

Comment: @onTheInternet: No, no, you supply it **in** the string: http://jsbin.com/elazug/1 (No need for the `/` in that.)

Comment: @onTheInternet: `<br />` needs to be *inside* the string.  `.innerHTML = "FAQ<br />Click";`

Comment: @onTheInternet: No worries, glad that helped! We should clean up these comments. :-)